# Openlayers : Prevent features icons overlay

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm using openlayers (v6.4.3) to display a map with features in different layers. I want to prevent overlay of feature's icons from different layers : if two of them overlap, I have to move one of the icons. I looked on the official openlayer's documentation but I can't find an option or a method to achieve that.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: There is an OpenLayers issue https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11449 which could also apply to icons.  Currently you would need to try one of the workarounds.

Comment: Hi @Mike thanks for your answer! I tried to use decluttering but it seemed to work between features in a layer, I didn't make it work from a layer to another. Am I missing something?