# Multi layering features open layers 6

Tags: javascript, feature-selection, openlayers-6

I'm using open layers 6 for an application.

I render mutltiple layers on a map.

On my map for exemple, I have 2 differents layers :

```
this.layers["PointOfInterest"] = new appli.map.PointOfInterestLayer(this.map, this.layersName.POI);
this.layers[this.layersName.POI].addLayer();
this.layers[this.layersName.POI].addFeaturesPOI();
                
this.layers["PHOTO"] = new appli.map.PhotoLayer(this.map, this.layersName.PHOTO);
this.layers[this.layersName.PHOTO].addLayer();
this.layers[this.layersName.PHOTO].addFeaturesPHOTO();
```

My layers :

```
appli.map.PointOfInterestLayer.prototype = {

    addLayer() {
       
        this.source = new ol.source.Vector({
                projection: config.projection
            });

        this[layerProperty] = new ol.layer.Vector({
            name: this.type,
            source: this.source,
            style: (feature) => this.getStyle(feature),
            zIndex: 1,
        });
        
        this.hoverInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
            layers:[this[layerProperty]],
        });
}
```

My problem is that, sometimes, the features are place at the exact same location on the map, and we can't see the entire icone representing it.
Is there a way to automatically move the feature to the closest place, in order to have the ability to clic on the 2 differents features ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043593/openlayers-prevent-features-icons-overlay  There is not much which can be done directly with OpenLayers unless you use decluttering, which may not be desirable in these cases.  In may be better to combine the layers and use clustering to indicate multiple features.

Comment: I use clustering for some layers, but the problem is that those layers can't be clustered in my case (due to functionnal restrictions)
I also tried decluttering, but it is no the good solution in my functionnal case ...